# How do I show user created node in user profile page with edit mode?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type 'child'. And I have give the permission to authenticated user to create child node. Its working fine.
But I need to show current user created node in user profile page with edit mode so user can easily updated own created node.
For this I have created views but I am not getting any option to show a created node as a edit form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permission for Edit own page for that role to see "Edit link" in views or any other page.

Tha can be available from

```
www.example.com/people/permissions -> <Content Type>: Edit own content
```

You have to create a module for showing your custom link in user profile page

```
function <modulename>_menu() {
 $items['user/%user/<yourlink>'] = array(
    'title' => 'Your Pages',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10,
  );
 return $items;
}
```

Not to mention you have to clear cache after the this.

Comment: Permission is working fine.. I need to show node on profile page with edit mode.

Comment: Update my answer please refer.

Comment: I need to show whole form in edit form with submit and delete button.And one user can create more than one link.